# JMS manifest file, does the order in which jars are specifid matter

Tags: java, jar, jms

In a manifest of a jar file, does the order in which the jars are listed matter.

Will the former jars be able to access the later jars.  Will the later jars be able to access the former jars

To clarify, I mean two jar files referenced with in the Rsrc-Class-Path: of the manifest

Thanks

Comment: No, the class loader loads them just the same, regardless of the order. - edit I should say no, with the exception of duplicate classes, in which case the first entity found by the class loader (not entirely sure if that equates to the first entry in the class path) is the class that gets used during runtime.

Comment: Also check this out: http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2005/01/26/classloading.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to expand on my comment, the answer is still No. The reason being, is because, with the exception of class path hackery (which I have done myself a time or two) Jar and class files are loaded by each ClassLoader before your code runs. The classes are only initialized when meaningful use is made in the application (like you access a static field, or create an instance). The point is, the ClassLoader uses the entries in its classpath to determine where to look when it loads up classes. When you try to use said classes, the ClassLoader already has a list of classes it can provide you with.

See the link I provided in my comment for more info on class loading.

Comment: Great answer.  My first time with a question.  I hit the check mark, but it will not allow me to vote up

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it matters, but not in the way you suggest.
The Oracle TechNote [Setting the class path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) says (right at the bottom):

> **Specification order**
>
> The order in which you specify multiple class path entries is
>   important. The Java interpreter will look for classes in the
>   directories in the order they appear in the class path variable.
>    In the example above,

(where they set the classpath to `C:\java\MyClasses;C:\java\OtherClasses`)

> the Java interpreter will first look for a needed class in the directory `C:\java\MyClasses`. Only if it doesn't find a class with the proper name in that directory will the interpreter look in the `C:\java\OtherClasses` directory.

Comment: This would be in the case of duplicate classes and whatnot correct? Meaning if somehow you deployed a build with a class path entry for V1.0 and a later entry for V1.1 of some API, classes from V1.0 would be used, instead of V1.1, which you might have intended.

Comment: Exactly! You need not worry about dependencies, the class loader figures that out, but different versions of the same class do matter.